# NIST Test Suit- igamc: UNDERFLOW

Tags: nist

I used a 32-bit random number generator 100,000 times, and resulted in a file of 275,714 bytes. Then I typed the following line in my terminal,

```
./access 1024 (Here comes my first question, what should we exactly type here?)
```

Then fed my file as input, then it come to

`"How many bitstreams?" 269`

Here 269( 269= 275,714/1024). And I chose Binary as my format. Finally,  I got numerous lines of "igamc: UNDERFLOW". What should I cope with this?

Answer (score 0):

NIST Test Suite can work on a number of bitstreams of certain length and its result can be then displayed as proportion of the bitstreams that passed test to all bitstreams (in **finalAnalysisReport** in **Proportion** column). So when you execute `./assess length`, length is the length of one bitstream.

I think that igamc underflow can be caused by too short bitstreams. In [NIST document](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-22r1a.pdf), for every test recommended input size is specified and e.g. for Binary Matrix Rank Test it's somewhere close to 40 000 and for Overlapping Template Matching Test it's 1 000 000 and both of these tests use igamc function to compute P-value.